# ValueOf() in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

From my `database.js` I export mongoose models for my three user types:

```
module.exports = {
    root: rootCol,
    advisor: advisorCol,
    student: studentCol,
};
```

In my `api.js`, I get usertype from `req.body.type` which will be either (`root`, `advisor` or `student`)

When I try:

```
var models = require('../database.js');

 models.req.body.type.valueOf().findOne({ ....
```

It says the thing doesn't have `findOne` method. I'm trying to access `models.root` or `models.advisor` without having to use if else statements. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: models[req.body.type].findOne(...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`models.req.body.type` means something like that:

```
{ 
  "models": {
   "req": {
    "body":{
     "type": ....
   }
  }
 }
}
```

To make Javascript resolves variable to its value, you have to use
`models[req.body.type]`.

It means getting a property's value in `models` by that property's name (the value of `req.body.type`)